# Crabgrass or thatch?

Tags: grass

[image]

Is this crabgrass or thatch-whatever it is how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great photo so it's hard to be certain but you don't normally see thatch. It's on the surface of the soil and partly embedded in it. What you most likely have is some sort of dead grass like plant.

Since crabgrass is an annual that dies off in winter that would be my first guess since it's starting to get cold.

Comment: I agree... this looks like crabgrass. Thatch is the remainder of lawn clippings that accumulate at the base of the grass shoots and sit on top of the soil.